# Top Navigation Menu is not visible in mobile view using GeneratePress premium

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the Generate Press premium theme My issue is simple but not able to troubleshoot yet. Top navigation on the header of the website is not visible when it collapses to the mobile view.
https://www.wowkitchenplace.in/

images
http://prtsc.ca/i/5wveSi ,
http://prtsc.ca/i/5wv0H2

I have no idea how to solve it. Please help me!
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a hamburger icon (3 horizontal stripes) in your mobile view? I can see it when I minimize the page.